# Grep part of string after symbol and shuffle columns

Tags: awk, sed

I would like to take the number after the `-` sign and put is as column 2 in my matrix. I know how to grep the string but not how to print it after the text string.

in:

```
1-967764        GGCTGGTCCGATGGTAGTGGGTTATCAGAACT
3-425354        GCATTGGTGGTTCAGTGGTAGAATTCTCGCC
4-376323        GGCTGGTCCGATGGTAGTGGGTTATCAGAAC
5-221398        GGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACGTGAAAATCTCGTATGCCGTCT
6-180339        TCCCTGGTGGTCTAGTGGTTAGGATTCGGCGCT
```

out:

```
GGCTGGTCCGATGGTAGTGGGTTATCAGAACT 967764
GCATTGGTGGTTCAGTGGTAGAATTCTCGCC 425354
GGCTGGTCCGATGGTAGTGGGTTATCAGAAC 376323
GGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACGTGAAAATCTCGTATGCCGTCT 221398
TCCCTGGTGGTCTAGTGGTTAGGATTCGGCGCT 180339
```

Comment: please show your efforts

Comment: You say you want to take the number _before_  the `-` but in the example you put the numbers _after_ the `-`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F'[[:space:]-]+' '{print $3,$2}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a simple substitution should do the job:

```
sed -E 's/[0-9]+-([0-9]+)[[:space:]]*(.*)/\2 \1/' file
```

Capture the parts you're interested in and use them in the replacement.

Alternatively, using awk:

```
awk 'sub(/^[0-9]+-/, "") { print $2, $1 }' file
```

Remove the leading digits and `-` from the start of the line. When this is successful, `sub` returns true, so the action is performed, printing the second field, followed by the first.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex `( +|-)` as field separator:

```
$ awk -F"( +|-)" '{print $3,$2}' file
GGCTGGTCCGATGGTAGTGGGTTATCAGAACT 967764
GCATTGGTGGTTCAGTGGTAGAATTCTCGCC 425354
GGCTGGTCCGATGGTAGTGGGTTATCAGAAC 376323
GGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACGTGAAAATCTCGTATGCCGTCT 221398
TCCCTGGTGGTCTAGTGGTTAGGATTCGGCGCT 180339
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another `awk`

```
$ awk 'split($1,a,"-") {print $2,a[2]}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/.-/,"");print $2,$1}' file
GGCTGGTCCGATGGTAGTGGGTTATCAGAACT 967764
GCATTGGTGGTTCAGTGGTAGAATTCTCGCC 425354
GGCTGGTCCGATGGTAGTGGGTTATCAGAAC 376323
GGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACGTGAAAATCTCGTATGCCGTCT 221398
TCCCTGGTGGTCTAGTGGTTAGGATTCGGCGCT 180339
```